# How to get the public snippets of a project without authentication?

Tags: gitlab-api

I can browse the public snippets of a project without authenticating, for example: https://gitlab.com/Boiethios/someproject/snippets.

I thus expect to access this information through a public API. However, the V4 API does not allow to do so: `GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/6165269/snippets` returns a `401`.

How can I do that?

Comment: I've posted this QA since I've had a hard time to find this information.

Answer (score 0):

The newest gitlab API uses GraphQL.

To get the snippets of a project, the following request can do the job:

```
query {
  project(fullPath: "username_or_group/projectname") {
    snippets {
      nodes {
        fileName,
        title,
        blob {
          rawPath
        }
        # You can query some other fields you want
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The request can be tested [here](https://gitlab.com/-/graphql-explorer).

The request must be posted as a body to the url: `https://gitlab.com/api/graphql`.